# SQL Compare table with .txt file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL table name- Master  which have Million of records and have Child1.txt file which have data. I have to remove the data from Master table which are not present in Child1.txt file. I am able to do it using import Child1.txt to temporary table and use left join.

The Problem is when I get Multiple `.txt` files eg. Child1.txt, Child2.txt, Child3.txt - Maximum allowed is 3 text file. The solution I came across is to use bulk insert by creating a temporary table and import all the 3 text files and compare with the master table.

I wanted to know if there was any other feasible solution to work on ????

Comment: I really don't understand the last part beginning with "Problem: Master table..."  Are you simply restating the issue or are you trying to say something else?  If restating, then the *Best* thing to do is exactly what you've already done: Import the files into a temp table, then do a join to find out the differences.

Comment: Combine those 3 text files and insert the result file into temp table. Simple as that

Comment: Okey now i have updated it. Yep wanted to know any other solution other than the one i have came across.

Comment: My question would be why.  If your solution works and is fast and meets your requirements - then why not go with it?  That is what programming is all about.